# Distinguishing HPL runs where N, NB, PxQ do not vary

Tags: hpc

I'm benchmarking my computing cluster with High-Performance Linpack 2.0. I just completed 16 runs for which certain tuning parameters vary, but others do not. In particular, the four parameters listed with the FLOPS score in the output (`N`, `NB`, `P`, and `Q`) do not vary. Because of this, I do not know how to distinguish the results in terms of those parameters that do vary (`PFACT`, `RFACT`, `BCAST`, and `DEPTH`).

The HPL output in question can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-65tlH-mjjVYgpq5GIHLDLAyv2pwFEGSZouS-O_QYBA/edit)

The corresponding [input file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iLyU_ErfkUoiGf5VzqmvN2tXBthzXj38DQMO7fndQvc/edit)

Any insights or ideas appreciated!

Comment: Your question is off-topic here as is it not related to programming. There is [another site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), dedicated to scientific computing.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, I did not know about that site. I also greatly appreciate that you answered my question anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of each run are encoded in the value of the `T/V` field, e.g.

```
WR00L2L4
 |||||||
 ||||||+-- NBMIN = 4
 |||||+--- PFACT = Left
 ||||+---- NDIV = 2
 |||+----- RFACT = Left
 ||+------ BCAST = 0 (1ring)
 |+------- DEPTH = 0
 +-------- possibly PMAP = Row-major
```

Parameter values are rotated starting with the last one. When all possible values are tested, the value of the previous one is changed and so forth.

Comment: @Hristolliev How did you determine the order? Is it documented somewhere, or did you simply deduce it by inspecting these input and output?

Comment: @AnantRathi, I have seen it documented somewhere a long time ago but couldn't find it so I had to improvise using deduction :)